# Euclidean Topology Sets

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

"**Is every set in the Euclidean Topology either open or closed? (exclusive or)**"

I would say that the answer is FALSE, because for example I can have the interval (1,2], which is open at 1 and closed at 2.

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: Should be false because the entire set of $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed.

Comment: Your example is fine: it is a subset of $\Bbb R$ that is neither open nor closed. Others have pointed out the other kind of counterexample, a set that is both open and closed; in $\Bbb R$ there are only two, $\varnothing$ and $\Bbb R$.

Comment: See this link for the completing answer. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/17659/8581

Comment: Beware though that the example you provided: $(1,2]$, is not both open and closed, but neither closed nor open, despite having one end 'open' and the other end 'closed'. Think about the definitions of open for this to make sense.

Comment: Thanks, @LevLivnev. Yes, I had to ponder at the problem for a sec. Thank you all for such a complex answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false, because $\mathbb{R}^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is always open and closed, and $\varnothing$ is clopen too.

In fact in every topological space there are at least 2 clopen sets, all the space, and the empty set. In addition a topological space $T$ is connected iff the only clopen sets are $T$ and $\varnothing$

Comment: In fact this answer (with trivial changes) apply to _all_ topologies, not just the Euclidean one.

Comment: i will add this thanks

Comment: I understand. Thank You.