# Z compact with another topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with a topology generated by the basis of the form $(-k,k)$, is a finite set, say (-3,3), compact? Is $\mathbb{Z}$ compact?

I think a finite set is compact since you can just find a finite (in fact singleton) subcover, that is the interval that includes all the points in the finite set. For the second part, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not for the same reason that it is not compact in the standard topology.

Can someone please check if what I am thinking is correct? Thanks

Comment: A finite set is compact in $\mathbf{any}$ topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. Suppose that $A \subseteq X$ so that $|A|<\infty$. Suppose that $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $A$. Then  we go ahead and choose $U_a$ so that $a \in U_a$. There are at most finitely many $U_a$. Then $A^{\prime}=\{U_a \mid a \in U_a\}$. But then there is a finite sub-collection so that $A \subseteq A^{\prime}$, hence $A$ compact. This is more general. Any finite set is compact.

I'm not sure what you meant by "singleton sub-cover," but the set of $\{x\} \subseteq X$ need not be open. See here for further discussion:
[Are Singleton sets in $\mathbb{R}$ both closed and open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17649/are-singleton-sets-in-mathbbr-both-closed-and-open)

Comment: AC is unnecessary. You have a finite amount of choices.

Comment: Is this true? What if the chosen subcover is infinite?

Comment: Point taken, you are correct. Will edit

Comment: So is it because we cannot use this reasoning that Z is not compact in this space?

Comment: What would it take to "cover" $\mathbb{Z}$? For every cover, is there a finite subcollection that suffices?