# Terminology - A set can be written as some disjoint subsets with no path from one to another

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Suppose $S$ is the union of two disjoint circles; consider each circle as one subset, there is no path from one subset to another one. Is there any special terminology for that?

Comment: Partition maybe?

Comment: I think you are referring to set $S$ being partitioned into its respective equivalence classes.

Comment: I mean the "name" of such kind of sets not description; we say $S$ is .... .

Comment: The new edit is a totally different question to the original. You should revert this question and ask another. However, the answer is that the space is not path connected. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness

Comment: @EvanRosica Path-connected; this is the case. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added this to my answer. If it was helpful feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the edited question:

We would say that the set is not path connected.

---

To answer the question as originally posed:

All sets can be written as a union of disjoint subsets. Say $S= \{s_1 ,s_2, \cdots , s_n \} $. Then $S$ is the union of the collection of all sets which are composed of exactly one element of $S$. More concisely, $S$ is the union of all its singleton subsets. Since any set has the property you described, the answer is simply a set.

For example, if $S= \{s_1 ,s_2, s_3 \}$, then $\cup \{ \{s_1 \} ,\{s_2\} ,\{s_3\}\}=\{s_1 ,s_2, s_3 \}=S$

Comment: Consider a square. Is it possible to write it as the union of its closed subsets? I edited the question.

Comment: @Amin this is a different question. Adding that the subsets must be closed means that the answer depends on the topology since closure is a topological property. If the topology is such that singleton sets are closed, then my answer stands.

Comment: This was in my mind; I knew your answer and that is the trivial case. I talk not about discrete case. Not necessarily closed.

Comment: My answer holds for any $T_1$ space, not just the discrete case. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17649/are-singleton-sets-in-mathbbr-both-closed-and-open

Comment: What do you mean by $T_1$?

Comment: @Amin Its a class of topological spaces in which points (singleton sets) are closed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space. See Jonas Meyer's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17649/are-singleton-sets-in-mathbbr-both-closed-and-open.

Comment: you may remove the first part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a union of pairwise disjoint sets.  Introduce
your own term but be sure to include a definition when you use it.